# Is this a ternary relationship? How do I model it in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

A truck has a unique identifier.

A truck_trip_route has a unique identifier, too.

A truck_team has a unique identifier, too.

Each truck has one team that services it. Each truck also goes on one trip route.

I need to be able to model this relationship and show this. I am guessing this is a ternary relationship?

I did some research and came across pivot tables, but I'm not sure if I am on the right track.

I know M:M relationships aren't allowed, but what if I model a ternary relationship and link them through a pivot table, is that better?

Comment: This is just two 1-to-1 relationships. Give the `truck` table a `truck_trip_route_id` column and a `truck_team_id` column.

Comment: Then you just join the tables using these columns as join conditions.

Comment: Why do you think many-to-many relationships aren't allowed?

Comment: There is no explicit indication that forbids one team to service more than one truck, nor that a trip route is traversed by more than one truck. Any such restrictions exist?

Comment: Does one team service just one truck?  Does only one truck go on a particular route?  My point is -- you have not finished specifying the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any extra tables. You can do it as follows:

[image]

The columns with an asterisk are the primary keys.

The *truck* table has two foreign keys which define uniquely which *truck team* and which *truck trip route* are associated with it.

If it is also required that a *truck team* can only service one *truck*, then put a unique index on the foreign key column *truck_team_id* in the *truck* table.

Similarly, if it is also required that a *truck trip route* can only be traversed by one *truck*, then put a unique index on the foreign key column *truck_trip_route_id* in the *truck* table.

Comment: that's what I am now planning on doing, very help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the description given a ternary relationship makes sense.
There's one truck with one team and one route. So a linking table that takes the IDs for each will work fine.

Otherwise another approach is to have direct links between the tables.
e.g.

```
Team (table) -> truck_team (link table) -> Truck (table) -> truck_route (link table) -> Route
```

It really depends on what form you want your tables in. Having a `truck` containing a `team_id` and `route_id` is also another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The statement "each truck has one team" sounds like a binary relationship. So too "each truck goes on one trip route". A ternary relationship would be something like "each truck has one team per trip route".

Comment: but isn't it bad to have many identifiers in one type of table? eg one table with 3 different unique id types? If I wanted to delete a Truck, i'd have to delete it off many tables if it is not a primary key

Comment: If a truck is involved in many relations, then deleting it would affect many tables. That's what cascading FK constraints are for. However, that's not "one table with 3 different unique id types". I'm not sure what you mean by many identifiers in one type of table.